# Backing out the function knowing its Taylor Series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

There are two similar questions in my complex analysis book that I can't for the life of me solve... They are about backing out a function given its Taylor Expansion.  I will state both and give my attempt on both

> (1) Find the holomorphic function whose Taylor Series expansion at $0$ is $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2 z^n \qquad \mbox{where } |z|<1 $$

The only obvious thing I can think of is to find a function $f$ such that $f^{(n)}(0) = n! n^2$, but really I am finding it impossible

> (2) Find the holomorphic function whose Taylor Series expansion at $0$ is $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^n \qquad \mbox{where } |z|<1/2 \mbox{ and } a_n = \begin{cases} 2^n & n \mbox{ even} \\ 1 & n \mbox{ odd} \end{cases} $$

I can think to break the problem down in the following way:
$$ f(z) = \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2^{2n} z^{2n} \right) + \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} z^{2n+1} \right) := g(z)+h(z)$$
Then I can find the function $g$ and $h$... But the problem is I can't see how to handle "Taylor Series" with the exponent being $2n$ and $2n+1$, how can I back out the original function?

Comment: Start with a function you know. Here, you should recognize $\sum z^n$.  Now differentiate that term by term and work from there.

Comment: @lulu Yes it worked for the first question, thanks!  Ive seen the trick many times but never saw that this question could use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the exercise is designed so that you use $\sum^\infty_{n=0}z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}=:h(z)$ together with the fact that $zh'(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=1} nz^n=z\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ and $z^2h''(z)=\sum^\infty_{n=2}(n^2-n)z^n=2z^2\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}$ in order to find the exact form of $\sum^\infty_{n=0}n^2z^n$ in terms of $\frac{1}{1-z}$. Try to work out the details from here.

Similarly, for the second function $g(z)$, you have
\begin{align}
g(z)&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}4^nz^{2n} + \sum^\infty_{n=0}z^{2n+1}\\
&=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(4z^2)^n+z\sum^\infty_{n=0}z^{2n}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-4z^2} + \frac{1}{1-z^2}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.  There is one detail I don't think looks right, but I can't myself work it out.  It's the part where $\sum_{n\geq 0} (4z^2)^n = 1/(1-2z^2)$. Should it not be $\sum_{n\geq 0} (4z^2)^n = 1/(1-4z^2)$? But then in that case, the radius of convergence is $1/4$ not $1/2$..

Comment: Yes, of course! I just made the appropriate corrections.